# Django: update choices field using human readable value?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am using Django 1.9. I have a model as follows:

```
class Report(models.Model):
    LANGUAGE_CHOICES = (
        ('EN', 'English'),
        ('CY', 'Welsh')
    )
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company)
    language = models.CharField(
        max_length=2,
        choices=LANGUAGE_CHOICES,
        default='EN'
    )
    pdf_url = models.URLField(blank=True)
```

Now I want to insert a value:

```
report_obj, created = Report.object.update_or_create(
    company=company, language='English')
```

But this fails with:

```
psycopg2.DataError: value too long for type character varying(2)
```

My data source contains "English" and "Welsh", not "EN" and "CY".

How can I update using the human readable name? Or do I need to maintain a separate lookup list from the human readable name to the short value in my import script?

Comment: Did you solve the problem??

Comment: Hi Richard, U can check human readable name in LANGUAGE_CHOICES field by using: key = [x[0] for x in LANGUAGE_CHOICES if 'English' in x] and pass this key into insert statement as per required format

Answer (score 1):

If your existing database already populated with this model ('EN'), and you have no interest in migrating it, yes you can use a lookup

```
CHOICES_LANGUAGE = dict(map(reversed, Report.LANGUAGE_CHOICES))
...
language=CHOICES_LANGUAGE['English']
```

Answer (score -1):

I think it should be:

```
# models
EN = 1
CY = 2

LANGUAGE_CHOICES = (
    (EN, 'English'),
    (CY, 'Welsh')
)

# then insert
report_obj, created = Report.object.update_or_create(
company=company, language=Report.EN)
```

Answer (score -1):

You get the error below because you are trying to insert a value bigger than the defined `max_length` (max_length=2):

> psycopg2.DataError: value too long for type character varying(2)

**NB:** The first element in each tuple is the actual value to be set on the model, and the second element is the human-readable name. In your case the actual value is also the human-readable name. You should also use a bigger `max_length` value since you are going to use the human-readable name format. Define your choices as follow:

```
class Report(models.Model):
    LANGUAGE_ENGLISH_CHOICE = 'English'
    LANGUAGE_WELSH_CHOICE = 'Welsh'
    LANGUAGE_CHOICES = (
        (LANGUAGE_ENGLISH_CHOICE, 'English'),
        (LANGUAGE_CHOICES, 'Welsh')
    )
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company)
    language = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        choices=LANGUAGE_CHOICES,
        default=LANGUAGE_ENGLISH_CHOICE
    )
    pdf_url = models.URLField(blank=True)
```

and then create you object as follow:

```
report_obj, created = Report.object.update_or_create(company=company, language=Report.LANGUAGE_ENGLISH_CHOICE)
```

Check here [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#choices) for more details.